# Summarizing dataframe by order id

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm working with a dataset that shows the quantity and price of a product that is part of a clients order. One order often exists out of multiple products, so multiple rows. I want to create a df with the total price and amount of products per order. I also would like to keep the date and customerid.

```
orders <- orders %>% 
          group_by(orderid) %>% 
          summarise(date, customerid, sum(product qty), sum(price))
```

I was initially thinking about the script above; however it returns the exact same amount of rows as I previously had, while I was hoping it would return only 1 row per orderid

Any advice?

Edit: thanks for the help! It helped a lot with getting the outcome I hoped for :)

Comment: why are you summarsing on `date` and `customer_id` when these are same for every group created?

Comment: I guess because I want them to be included in the output dataframe but I am not sure how to do that in combination with a summarise dplyr function. Do you have advice?

Comment: Group_by columns will also be added in output

Comment: See, the answer proposed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```r
library(magrittr)

tibble::tibble(order_id = c(rep(1, 50), rep(2, 50)),
               A = rnorm(100, 5),
               B = rnorm(100, -5)) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(order_id) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise_at(dplyr::vars(c("A","B")), sum) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   order_id     A     B
#>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1        1  270. -250.
#> 2        2  258. -260.
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I created some sample data to show you how to proceed

```
> dput(orders)
structure(list(order_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), date = c("01-01-2020", 
"01-01-2020", "01-01-2020", "02-01-2020", "02-01-2020", "02-01-2020"
), customer_id = c("C1", "C1", "C1", "C2", "C2", "C3"), product_id = c("P1", 
"P2", "P3", "P4", "P5", "P1"), prod_qty = c(10L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 
3L, 5L), price = c(5L, 20L, 15L, 16L, 23L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

> orders
  order_id       date customer_id product_id prod_qty price
1        1 01-01-2020          C1         P1       10     5
2        1 01-01-2020          C1         P2        2    20
3        1 01-01-2020          C1         P3        5    15
4        2 02-01-2020          C2         P4        2    16
5        2 02-01-2020          C2         P5        3    23
6        3 02-01-2020          C3         P1        5     5
```

Now proceed like this

```
orders %>% group_by(order_id, date, customer_id) %>%
  summarise(products_purchased = n_distinct(product_id),
            total_price = sum(prod_qty*price)) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 3 x 5
  order_id date       customer_id products_purchased total_price
     <int> <chr>      <chr>                    <int>       <int>
1        1 01-01-2020 C1                           3         165
2        2 02-01-2020 C2                           2         101
3        3 02-01-2020 C3                           1          25
```

I think this will solve your problem and doubts why to include `date` and `customer_id` in `group_by` statement.  This will have as many rows only as you have distinct order_ids